# arguments for choosing rest style web services instead of soap

Tags: web-services, rest, soap

We are about to decide a common approach for intranet web services.

I find rest style web services much elegant and easier to implement.

I'd like to have more information about the pros of using rest style ws

Comment: I've heard that google and yahoo are deprecating it's soap interfaces, and new services are choosing rest... that's a fine argument

Answer (score 3):

The computing world is definetly leaning towards REST these days.

Principle advantages are:

- Easier to setup service, as it can be as simple as installing a web sever and placing some resources in the file system.
- Easier to implement service, you don't have to worry about complex XML's, WSDL, XSD with all the trimings thats make it hard to see what they are trying to represent and even harder to debug.
- Better Performance, the additional data required in soap messages for namespaces, envelopes etc.. can lead to a big overhead which over time can have an impact specifically with mobile devices, especially when compared to return JSON messages.
- Easier to develop clients for as you can implement a simple parser to process the response and if your client is javascript the use of JSON objects can be very advantages. It's also clearer to see what you are receiving.
- It's how the internet was initailly designed to work, http is set up for this sort of interaction.
- I hate SOAP

Comment: +1 for the I hate SOAP (Hey, I didn't say the arguments should be objective)

Comment: I don't see what's so bad about SOAP.
REST looks a bit too loose and wishy washy to me.
I like my contracts and schemas.
Of course it's probably a pain in the arse to consume SOAP with Javascript but luckily I really couldn't care less about JS |-)

Comment: @RoboJ1m I think I was struggling with some poorly written Web services when I wrote this. For me it's the complexity from reading to writing to configuring. Although I understand there are some places where SOAP is beneficial I think it tends to be unnecessary in most circumstances. Even if it does feel more comfortable for you to use you have to consider the poor people that have to use and maintain it who need to learn WSDL and SOAP from scratch.

Comment: As it happens I'm back on the WSDL/SOAP wagon at the moment so I'm reading all about it, trying to find better ways of doing it. These days, if I had to be honest, I think what I actually really love is WSDL+XSD, not SOAP. SOAP's just the envelope. If you can apply WSDL+XSD to REST then who cares what maps an HTTP payload to a DLL call? Shortly after I read that I found a tool called WSCF.blue which is an automation toolkit for practising what's called Contract First development using WCF, WSDL and XSD. Turns out we've been doing that for the last 5 years and just didn't know what it was

Comment: called (and I though a was being so original :'( ). The trick is to write your schemas, generate the WSDL, generate the SOAP or REST skeleton framework and distribute the work amongst the developers :). Now if I can just figure our a way to generate Word documents documenting the API from the WSDL and the XSDs I'm the happiest man alive.

Comment: I used contract first development with Spring WS services, my problem came in when we were passed WSDLs that other people had made to maintain and build upon. If they didn't comply with WSDL standards and it created problems when trying to build on their WSDLs we had to understand all the intricacies of the standard to see what was going wrong. Why put someone through that if it isn't necessary.

Answer (score 2):

for me, [this](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/431.cfm) sums it up...

> The main advantages of REST web
>   services are: Lightweight - not a lot
>   of extra xml markup, Human Readable
>   Results, Easy to build - no toolkits
>   required
>
> SOAP also has some advantages: Easy to
>   consume - sometimes Rigid - type
>   checking, adheres to a contract,
>   Development tools